# Sorting 2 lists

Tags: python, python-2.7, sorting

I am looking for simple way to sort 2 lists at once. I need to sort first list containing strings by alphabet a same way sort second list containing integers. Data of lists are related (first[1] is related with second[1] ... ). So I need to keep same index for the pair with same index from both lists.
For example:

```
first = ["B","C","D","A"]   
second = [2,3,4,1]
```

I would like to sort it like this:

```
first = ["A","B","C","D"]  
second = [1,2,3,4]
```

I am not sure if is it even possible to do that simple way.

Comment: The top answer looks good, but it sounds like you should be using tuples or even better a Pandas Dataframe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `zip()` them, sort and then unzip (though I don't fully understand the use case):

```
>>> first = ["B","C","D","A"]   
>>> second = [2,3,4,1]
>>> 
>>> zip(first, second)
[('B', 2), ('C', 3), ('D', 4), ('A', 1)]
>>> first_new, second_new = zip(*sorted(zip(first, second)))
>>> first_new
('A', 'B', 'C', 'D')
>>> second_new
(1, 2, 3, 4)
```

Answer (score 0):

try to using tuple
visit [wiki.python.org](https://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting)
ex:

```
>>> student_tuples = [  
        ('john', 'A', 15),  
        ('jane', 'B', 12),  
        ('dave', 'B', 10),  
]  
>>> sorted(student_tuples, key=lambda student: student[2])   # sort by age
```

**output**

```
[('dave', 'B', 10), ('jane', 'B', 12), ('john', 'A', 15)]
```

Answer (score 0):

or you could use dicts:

```
>>> d = {"B":2,"C":3,"D":4,"A":1}
>>> sorted(d)
['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
>>> d["A"]
1
>>> d["C"]
3
>>> for i in sorted(d):
    print(d[i])

1
2
3
4
```